# LoRaWAN remote sensor node platform

Tags: sensors, lora, lorawan

Which platform can you recommend for a LoRa/LoRaWAN remote sensor node, which fulfills the following criteria?

- Detects presence of people in 15-minute interval (e.g. with a RCWL-0516)
- Reports the data also in 15-minute interval (alternatively 1x/day)
- Battery life approx. 1 year: 10 x 5 cm top surface can accomodate a solar cell, but energy harvesting also okay. We were thinking of using TP4056 with 18650s.
- Location (see elevation profile below): Sensor at the top of a hill (altitude ~400m) with

  - Option 1: Nearly line-of-sight to an urban location (antenna at ~10m above ground)
  - Option 2: Line-of-sight to an urban location (antenna at ~150m on the roof of a building)
- Cost around 50 EUR/60 USD

[image: Option 1]
[image: Option 2]

Comment: have you done any research? .... if yes, then what was the result?

Answer (score 1):

You may try a PIR-LAB-51NS / PIR-LAB-41NS. SenlabP Passage detection sensor:
https://sensing-labs.com/senlab-passage-detection-indoor/

It is a LoRaWAN end device with passive infrared detector.

Comment: The link is broken can you put the referred device into the answer itself?

Comment: Reference: PIR-LAB-51NS / PIR-LAB-41NS. SenlabP Passage detection sensor.